# WPF Window Semi Transparent. Is it possible to make underneath clickable?

Tags: wpf

I have the following WPF Window:
http://uploadffs.nl/images/2015/09/09/Untitled.png

I am unable to click the folder if the mouse is on the blue window, note that the window is set to *"Topmost"*.

I have noticed that setting the background to *transparent*, I am able to click anything underneath the window.

**Code:**

```
 <Border BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.5" CornerRadius="50,50,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Background="#FF5A9AE0"/>
```

Comment: Is the folder on your desktop?

Comment: Yes, the folder is on my desktop. The window is on top of everything practically.

Comment: Try setting IsHitTestVisible="False"

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: Indeed! That worked. Thanks a lot :D.

Comment: I don't know how, but I think you can choose to accept that it is a duplicate and it will close the question.